# How to create a secure link (https) with CakePHP's HtmlHelper

Tags: cakephp, ssl, hyperlink, cakephp-2.4

I've looked everywhere and can't find out how to create a secure link (https) using CakePHP's HtmlHelper.

Seems like this should be a simple option, but... apparently it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up just extending the HtmlHelper and allowing the user (me) to pass `'_secure'=>true` as an option (see below).

This could, of course, be extended, cleaned up...etc, but - it works great for my purpose.

**The custom 'MyHtmlHelper':**

```
<?php
//app/View/Helper/MyHtmlHelper.php
App::uses('HtmlHelper', 'View/Helper');
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper {

    public function link($title, $url = null, $options = array(), $confirmMessage = false) {
        if(!empty($url['_secure']) && $url['_secure'] === true) {
            unset($url['_secure']);
            $url = str_replace('http:', 'https:', parent::url($url));
        }
        return parent::link($title, $url, $options, $confirmMessage);
    }

}
```

**Explanation:**

The basic idea is that it checks if you've passed 'secure' as an option in your options array.  If you do, it forces the link to be 'full_base' (ie a full URL with `http://`...), then builds the URL into a string and replaces the 'http:' with 'https:'

**How to use:**

```
echo $this->Html->link('SSL LINK!', array(
    'controller' => 'orders',
    'action'     => 'tickets',
    'full_base'  => true,
    'secure'     => true
));
```

**Reminder:**

You have to tell your app that you want to use YOUR helper as the HtmlHelper:

```
public $helpers = array(
    'Html' => array('className' => 'MyHtml'),
);
```

Comment: You are not taking secure=>false into account, though. That could lead to strange results regarding the final URL.

Comment: @mark - Why would I ever pass `'secure'=>false`?  The links are not https by default, and 'secure' is not an option for the normal helper.  Seems kind of like saying I didn't take into account if they pass `'dave'=>'likes pizza'`, no?  (maybe I'm missing something?)

Comment: It is a boolean value, just like admin=>true/false or any other one. So false is supposed to turn it off - instead of adding a named param here. Just saying.

Comment: @mark - false is not "supposed" to do anything - it's not a CakePHP option at all.  It's not supposed to be available as a true/false boolean - this is simply a workaround to allow you to easily create SSL links using the Helper.  Side note: I've changed it to check specifically for `=== true` in case they actually want to pass 'secure' as a URL param or something.

Comment: Not if used in different methods which - similar to admin=>true/false - can enable and disable https. there the only workaround otherwise would be to remove the key from the array, which is pretty annoying. Your modification still doesnt take that into account. I merely pointed out a flaw in your code that if accepted as answer should be considered in the actual implementation. No need to further adjust it yourself. I would have used isset() and called unset() then either way.

Comment: @mark - I understand your point - just seems overkill-negativity for something that is just meant as a workaround.  And un-setting regardless would keep anyone from ever using 'secure' as a url param - more of an annoyance IMO than just using this as-is. If you want a link secure, tell it to be secure. Otherwise, don't.  By doing it this way, then the ONLY way it will ever affect your URL is if you specifically want it to do the thing it's built for - for making a link secure.  (guess we can agree to disagree) :)

Comment: I guess that is why most "special" url options are prefixed with an underscore after all (so `_secure` in this case for example). Especially in the newer cake versions (namingly 3.0). Sidenote: In 3.0 this will be supported as `_scheme` option. So it might make sense to backport this to 2.x if you really need it.

Comment: Was this ever implemented in CakePHP 3.x?

Comment: It seems to be possible by passing "_ssl"  => true into the $url array https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/src/Routing/Router.php#L644